# springboot spring datasource tomcat properties not working

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I am working on a springboot application with spring jpa with spring starter version `<version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>`

I have defined below properties for tomcat and also excluded HikariCP **NOTE: HikariCP is also not working**

`application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=30
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=60000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=300
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=30
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true
```

I've tried all combinations and also used default but I am getting below error after 2-3 API calls .

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : [http-nio-8080-exec-5] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:4; busy:
4; idle:0; lastwait:30000].
```

Comment: Unfortunately the properties alone aren't enough to diagnose the problem. Are you sure that the auto-configured `DataSource` is being used?  If your application defines a `DataSource` bean of its own, those properties will have no effect. A [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve) would be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the deployment. I am deploying the app to cloudfoundry, and it by default adds profile called `cloud`. So, I created a bean of DataSource for "cloud" profile like below:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public class CloudConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        PooledServiceConnectorConfig.PoolConfig poolConfig = new PooledServiceConnectorConfig.PoolConfig(20, 300, 30000);
        DataSourceConfig dbConfig = new DataSourceConfig(poolConfig, null);
        return connectionFactory().dataSource(dbConfig);
    }
}
```